# Creating an element-wise minimum Series from two other Series in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am having trouble finding a way to do an efficient element-wise minimum of two Series objects in pandas. For example I can add two Series easily enough:

```
In [1]:
import pandas as pd
s1 = pd.Series(data=[1,1,1], index=[1,2,3])
s2 = pd.Series(data=[1,2,2,1], index=[1,2,3,4])
s1.add(s2)    
Out[1]:
1     2
2     3
3     3
4   NaN
dtype: float64
```

But I cannot find an efficient way to do an element-wise minimum between two Series (along with aligning the indices and handling NaN values).

*Nevermind. There is an escape hatch with the combine function so you can put in any element-wise function:*

```
In [2]:
s1 = pd.Series(data=[1,1,1], index=[1,2,3])
s2 = pd.Series(data=[1,2,2,1], index=[1,2,3,4])
s1.combine(s2, min, 0)
Out[2]:
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I think you should add the bit after "nevermind" as an answer, rather than at the end of the question (I'd upvote)... Although I disagree that `min(1, NaN) == 0`....

Comment: Yeah! You should answer your own question, so it has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 66):

I find this the simplest:

```
import numpy as np

smax = np.minimum(s1, s2)
```

[Link to docs (numpy.minimum)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html)

Comment: Numpy ignores indexes, so this only works if the two series have the same index in the same order.

Comment: Short and sweet!

Answer (score 55):

The most straightforward way I can see is to make them into a DataFrame and then take the row-wise min:

```
>>> print pandas.concat([s1, s2], axis=1).min(axis=1)
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
dtype: float64
```

Comment: On pandas 0.19.2 this is faster than other ways by more than three orders of magnitude

Answer (score 28):

Another similar way:

```
In [11]: pd.DataFrame([s1, s2]).min()
Out[11]:
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
dtype: float64
```

Comment: This only works for me on pandas 0.17 if I call `min(axis = 1)`

Comment: May I adjust the example to make it equal to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54807176/562769 ?

Answer (score 12):

```py
pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5]).clip(upper=pd.Series([6,5,4,3,2]))
```

will get you:

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    3
4    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This one is nice because it supports `inplace=` as well, if needed.

Comment: As a follow-up, I did a quick test on some random data and `.clip` was also _much_ faster than the `pd.concat` technique, by nearly 40x.

Answer (score 3):

You can concat the dataframes and take the minimum, specifying `level=0`:

```
>>> s1 = pd.Series(data=[1,1,1], index=[1,2,3])
>>> s2 = pd.Series(data=[1,2,2,1], index=[1,2,3,4])
>>> pd.concat([s1, s2]).min(level=0)
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
dtype: int64
```

This approach also [works on dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51159504/4901005).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `combine` method of a DataFrame with `np.minimum` as the argument.  `np.minimum` has special handling for NaN and complex NaNs.

Indeed, the [pandas docs for combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine.html) uses the `np.minimum` function to illustrate a "true element-wise combine":

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [5, 0], 'B': [2, 4]})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1], 'B': [3, 3]})
>>> df1.combine(df2, np.minimum)
   A  B
0  1  2
1  0  3
```

Answer (score 2):

This method will do the job:

```
import pandas as pd


def elementwise_min(x, y):
    x[x > y] = y
    return x


a = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
b = pd.Series([0, 2, 4])
elementwise_min(a, b)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [clip method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html):

```
>>> s1.clip(upper=s2)
1    1
2    1
3    1
dtype: int64

>>> s2.clip(upper=s1)
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as Andy Hayden, but a bit easier to read:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s1 = pd.Series(data=[1,2,3,4,5], index=[1,2,3,4,5])
>>> s2 = pd.Series(data=[5,1,3,5], index=[1,2,3,4])
>>> pd.DataFrame([s1, s2]).min()
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    3.0
4    4.0
5    5.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: It's better to help edit Andy's answer to make it easier to read, than to submit a duplicate answer.

Comment: @KenWilliams What is easy to read is personal preference (at least in this case).

Answer (score 1):

One straight-forward way is to use [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) function:

```
min_s1_s2 = s1.where(s1 < s2, s2)
```

`where` is a fundamental method in terms of which `clip` can be implemented, but not the other way around.